# asp.net selectedvalue bind conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I like to do a conditional bind. For example if the SelectedValue is null,
I like to bind it to "Pacific Time".
Below does not work but will give you an idea of what I am trying to do

```
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Zone") ?? "Pacific Time" %>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Zone") != null ? (string)Bind("Zone") : "Pacific Time" %>'
```

Comment: I get the following message: : The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


               <EditItemTemplate>
                
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeZone" runat="server" DataSource='<%# TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Select(s => s.Id) %>'
              SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Zone") != null ? (string)Bind("Zone") : "Pacific Time" %>' > 
         </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: try Eval instead of Bind please

Comment: Thanks but I need to do 2 way binding

Comment: You can't, use @PapaBurgundy suggestion in that case

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you're asking, but in your data source can you make the value Pacific if it's NULL?